# E0289 Отсутствуют экземпляры конструктора "Films::Films", соответствующие списку аргументов

Tags: visual-c++

Пробовал выставлять константы, пробовал убирать первый аргумент и параметр, но ошибка просто переходила на следующий, пробовал создавать переменную внутри функции и вставлять её аргументом, пробовал просто число вставлять.

'''

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int number = 0;
const int n = 50, g = 20, m = 100;
int mass[m];

class Films {
  int num = 0;
  char name[n], ganre[g];
  bool w_unw;
public:
  Films(int num_1, char *name_1, char *ganre_1[g], bool w_unw_1) {
  name[n] = *name_1;
      w_unw = w_unw_1;
  };
}  

void insert() {
  char name[n], ganre[g], * name_1, *p_ganre;
  bool w_unw;
  int a = 0;
  cout << "Введите название\n";
  cin >> name;
  name_1 = name;
  cout << "Введите жанр\n";
  cin >> ganre;
  p_ganre = ganre;
  cout << "Фильм просмотрен?(1 - да, 0 - нет)\n";
  cin >> w_unw;
  Films film(number, *name_1, *p_ganre, w_unw);
  if (number < n) { number++; }

}
```

'''

[Место, где показывает ошибку](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xe05w.png)

Answer (score 0):

Смотрим:

```
Films film(number, *name_1, *p_ganre, w_unw);
```

`number` у вас `int`, `name_1` — `char*`, `p_ganre` — `char*`, `w_unw` — `bool`.

Значит, вы передаете в конструктор

```
Films film(int, char, char, bool);
```

Есть у вас такой конструктор? Нет. У вас есть

```
Films(int, char*, char*[g], bool)
```

Так что компилятор прав. Предавайте конструктору то, что пообещали в объявлении/определении.

Comment: Простите немного не понял Я прочитал предложенные вами правки и, хоть считаю, что они малоэффективны, исправил код, но это не возымело эффекта 
` Films(int num_1, char *name_1, char *ganre_1, bool w_unw_1) `
` Films film(a, *p_name, *p_ganre, w_unw) `
Есть ещё варианты решения или я на этом этапе что-то не так сделал?

Comment: Это не правки! Это пояснение ситуации. Решение — передавать конструктору аргументы нужных типов.

Comment: Как скажете. В общем-то проблему я решил, может это решение вы и имели в виду, но это уже не так важно 
         ` Films(int num_1, char *name_1, char *ganre_1, bool w_unw_1)
           Films film(number, p_name, p_ganre, w_unw); `

Comment: Вот! Отлично. Теперь, когда вы *сами* решили — вы это запомните практически навсегда. Подсказанное же *готовое* решение продержалось бы очень недолго...